# How to fix 'WARNING: package sun.awt.X11 not in java.desktop' in jmeter while executing in Non Gui mode in Mac terminal?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I'm trying to run my test through non gui mode. But it throws the warning in my Mac terminal.

Answer (score 8):

You can ignore this warning it has no impact.

An alternative is to use jdk 8

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of that message, change the JAVA_HOME environment variable in your jmeter script from `openjdk` to `jdk 8`.

Before:

```
$ cat $(which jmeter)
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/opt/openjdk" exec "/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.4.3/libexec/bin/jmeter"  "$@"
```

After:

```
$ cat $(which jmeter)
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home" exec "/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.4.3/libexec/bin/jmeter"  "$@"
```

My answer is just adding on what @[UBIK LOAD PACK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/460802/ubik-load-pack) rightly pointed out.

Hope this helped.